# Electron Node.js node localstorage osx mkdir permission denied

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I am working with Electron and Node.js. We have developed an application that works fine on windows and as a requirement had to package it for mac os. I packaged the application using electron-packager, the packaging process completes and package is generated. Double clicking it throws an error that permission denied for mkdir, as i am using node localstorage to maintain some settings on the user's local machine. somehow mac doesn't local storage to create folder in the root of the application. Any help in this matter will be great. Thanks

Comment: In the root of the application? Show some code, please.

Comment: var LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage;

var localStorage = new LocalStorage("./errorLogDb");

Comment: try using LocalStorage without the second command, just LocalStorage('akey', 'aValue'); as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, is the code in question in the main process or in a renderer process? If it is the latter, you don't need to use 'node-localstorage', because you can use the renderer's native LocalStorage. If you are in the main process, then you need to provide your own storage strategy so using 'node-localstorage' is a viable option.

In any case, you need to carefully consider where to store the data; for starters, let's look at where Electron's renderer processes would store its LocalStorage data: this differs based on the OS, but you can [get and set the paths using the `app` module](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.5/api/app/#appgetpathname) -- the path in question is `userData`, which on OS X would default to `~/Library/Application Support/<App Name>`. Electron uses that folder to persist cookies, caches, LocalStorage etc. so I would suggest using that folder as well. (Otherwise, refer to XDG defaults for good defaults)

What your example above was trying to do is store your 'errorLogDb' in the current working directory, which might depend on your OS, where your App is installed, how you executed it, etc.

Finally, it's a good idea to differentiate between your 'production' app and your app during development and testing, because you might not want to use the same storage folders for every environment. In any case, just writing to './errorLogDb' is likely to cause lots of headaches so I'd be thankful for the permission denied error.

Comment: Thanks i will try change the folder location as per your suggestion and will update.

Answer (score 0):

this strategy worked for me:

```
const { LocalStorage } = require('node-localstorage');
let ls;

mb.on('ready', () => {
  let prefsPath = mb.app.getPath('userData') + '/prefs';
  ls = new LocalStorage(prefsPath);
  loadPrefs();
});

mb.on('after-create-window', () => { /* ls... */ }

exports.togglePref = () => { /* ls... */ }
```